# Vibrate Jelly Bean default mode - Android

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-4.3-jelly-bean, vibration, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Ok, I know the mess with the vibration settings in Jelly Bean. Nevertheless, I am developing an app and I'm trying to deal with the *Applications should maintain their own vibrate policy based on current ringer mode that can be queried via getRingerMode()*.

I am testing with WhatsApp because is the app I use the most. So, In WhatsApp Settings->Notification->Vibrate I have "Default" as the selected option. Then, as AudioManager class allows, in my code I can change between the three different modes of Android:

```
int RINGER_MODE_NORMAL  Ringer mode that may be audible and may vibrate.
int RINGER_MODE_SILENT  Ringer mode that will be silent and will not vibrate.
int RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE Ringer mode that will be silent and will vibrate.
```

Good, then, in VIBRATE mode, WhatsApp vibrates, on the other hand, in the Silent mode WhatsApp doesn't vibrate (following the rule *will not vibrate*), I am not sure if this default rule in Silent mode it is possible to change or not. But the thing I am more concerned about is the Normal mode rule *and may vibrate*.

Now, in Normal mode and the Default setting in WhatsApp configuration, the notification vibrates. I am trying to find a way to toggle this "Default" with my application to on or off. Because I am assuming this "Default" is a thing of the system not of the WhatsApp. So I would be able to be in the Normal mode and change the default vibrate notifications (as the default notification tone) to vibrate on/off.